# how to load vaadin jar from local system in eclipse instead of downloading it

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, vaadin, vaadin7

how to load vaadin jar from local system in eclipse instead of downloading it.

When i create a new vaadin project eclipse starts downloading vaadin jar from internet and takes lot time. how to stop this and instead of downloading jar again n again eclipse load vaadin jar from local system i.e vaadin-all-7.5.6 folder.

Comment: The build process is maven "powered", sou you must provide a local maven repository which provides all the different vaadin jar files. But the setup & config of such a repository isn't a simple task...

Comment: thanks alot André Schild. for your help and support in learning vaadin